# Cancelling query using SqlCommand.Cancel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to create a way to cancel a query to a SQL Server database (using ADO.net) by using `SqlCommand.Cancel`. As explained in other articles on `SqlCommand.Cancel`, I run a thread to govern the cancellation of the `SqlCommand`. Whenever I want to trigger the cancellation, I will set the `cancelQuery` variable to true, but whenever I trigger the query cancelling, nothing is happening (no exception thrown either) and the query continue.

Is there anything that I did wrong here?

```
    public void FillDataSet(string statement, string name, DataSet d)
    {
        trackFillThread = new Thread(() => CancelQuery());
        trackFillThread.Start();
        trackFillThread.IsBackground = true;

        LoadData(statement, name, d);            
    }

    void LoadData(string statement, string name, DataSet d)
    {
        connectionString = string.Format("data source={0};initial catalog={1};uid={2};pwd={3};Connection Timeout=80", dataSource, catalog, uid, pwd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = name;
        Debug.Log(name);

        using (SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            oConn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, oConn);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;

            try
            {
                Debug.Log("Start Query");
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                d.Tables.Add(dt);
                //cancelQuery = true;
            }
            catch //(System.Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Load Data Exception");
                return;
            }
        } 
    }

    void CancelQuery()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (cancelQuery)
            {
                cancelQuery = false;

                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Cancel");
                    cmd.Cancel();
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
        Debug.Log("CancelQuery Thread Ends");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

cancelQuery variable is set to true after filling the datatable and closely just before exiting from the function. So there is nothing to cancel as datatable is filled already after executing the command and reading data from the reader.

Comment: It literally does not work. It does not cancel a query. If you have a long-running sproc, calling SqlCommand.Cancel does nothing. If you pass a CancellationToken to ExecuteReader and cancel it, nothing happens. It just DOES NOT WORK. It always runs to completion.